Spring boot 3 Webflux Mongo connection leaks
We had an application with spring boot 2 without problems.
After upgrade it on spring boot 3 we have problem with connections to mongodb.
Our checkedout connections piling up to maxPoolSize and then application is crash.
attaching an image below how it looks like, maxPoolSize by default equals 100
what could be the reason?


Which Spring Boot version. Spring BOot 3 covers, 3.0 till 3.4 so that is quite a range. With other database access I would say that this is due to messing around with connections yourself without proper tx boundaries.

We set spring-boot 3.3.3

Have you tried 3.3.5 which is the most recent 3.3 version?

We can't set 3.3.5 now because we have problem with mutated request headers in this version, but it another question. We set 3.2.12 and everything is ok. We will understand further – –
